# How to get rid of multiple nested switchMap with early returns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I got 3 endpoints that returns upcoming, current, past events. I should show only the one that is the farthest in the future. To optimize the calls and not to call all the endpoints at once.I have written a simple RxJs stream where I call the first endpoint and if it does not return data I call second and so on. The code looks like this:

```js
this.eventsService.getUpcoming(id).pipe(
      switchMap((upcoming) => {
        if (upcoming.length) {
          return of(upcoming);
        }
        return this.eventsService.getCurrent(id).pipe(
          switchMap((current) => {
            if (current.length) {
              return of(current);
            }
            return this.eventsService.getPast(id)
          })
        );
      }),
    // some other pipe operators map etc.
```

It is possible not to have nested switch map within a switch map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use just `concat()` to make the calls sequential and then `take(1)` and `skipWhile()` to automatically complete when the first useful response arrives:

```
concat(
  this.eventsService.getUpcoming(id),
  this.eventsService.getCurrent(id),
  this.eventsService.getPast(id)
).pipe(
  skipWhile(response => response.length === 0),
  defaultIfEmpty([]),
  take(1),
);
```

`take(1)` will complete the chain when the first item in `skipWhile` doesn't match the condition.

Comment: One problem I see with this solution is that in case none of the calls return any data the observable will complete without any emit.

Comment: That's true. You can use `defaultIfEmpty()` to make sure it always emits at least once.

Comment: Marked as an answer as it is the cleanest of the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
this.eventsService.getUpcoming(id).pipe(
  switchMap((upcoming) => {
    if (upcoming.length) {
       return of(upcoming);
    }
    return this.eventsService.getCurrent(id)
  },
  switchMap((current) => {
     if (current.length) {
       return of(current);
     }
     return this.eventsService.getPast(id)
  })
)
```

This way you do not nest the `switchMap`

Comment: Yeah, this works because both switchMap do the same check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *concat* operator to create an observable which sequentially emits values from each observable.  Pipe the results to the *find* operator that will return the result from the first result that meets the condition and complete the observable.  This will prevent subsequent observables to be executed from the stream created by *concat*.

**Difference between first and take**

One side effect of *find* that I think you will find useful for your example is that if no conditions are met, then the last result is still emitted.  This is different then using an operator like *first* which will throw an error if the source observable completes without a match, or *take* which won't emit anything since a prior operator would be used for filtering emissions.

So in your case you'll at least get an empty array if all responses are empty.

```
concat(
  // try each request in order.
  this.eventsService.getUpcoming(id),
  this.eventsService.getCurrent(id),
  this.eventsService.getPast(id)
).pipe(
  // emits the first result that meets the condition.
  find(response => response.length > 0) 
);
```